# Trace distance of two classical-quantum states

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, trace-distance, cq-states

I have these two classical-quantum states:

$$\rho = \sum_{a} \lvert a\rangle \langle a\lvert \otimes q^a \\
 \mu = \sum_{a} \lvert a\rangle \langle a\lvert \otimes r^a $$

Where $a$ are the classical basis vectors, $q^a, r^a$ are arbitrary matrices dependent on $a$.

Now, we can take the [trace distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_distance) of these two classical-quantum states, which would be:

$$T(\rho, \mu) = \frac{1}{2} ||\rho - \mu||_1 \\
= \frac{1}{2} || \sum_a \lvert a\rangle \langle a\lvert \otimes(q^a - r^a)||_1$$

Now, my question is, can we rewrite the above expression in the following way?

$$T(\rho, \mu) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_a ||q^a - r^a||_1$$
I.e. just pulling the summation out of the norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, since the trace norm is the sum of the absolute value of the singular values, and the singular values can be found for each of the $a$ blocks independently.

Comment: is it like saying absolute(eig(A+B)) = abs(eig(A)) + abs(eig(B)) ?

Comment: @HasanIqbal No, this is wrong, just take B=-A.  It is like saying $\mathrm{abs}(\mathrm{eig}(A\oplus B)) = \mathrm{abs}(\mathrm{eig}(A))+\mathrm{abs}(\mathrm{eig}(B))$.

Comment: this is perfect... :) thanks Norbert